# Keras: ImportError: No module named data_utils

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import, keras

I am trying to import the module `keras.utils.data_utils` but its not working. However, I can find this module [here](https://github.com/fluency03/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/data_utils.py). It is indeed existing. Why I cannot import it while I can import some other modules like`keras.models` and `keras.layers.core`?

```
cliu@cliu-ubuntu:bin$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> from keras.models import Sequential 
>>> from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout 
>>> from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
>>> from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named data_utils
```

**Edit:**

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35911254/4802797) for the answer.

Comment: why did you include the `python-3.x` tag if you are clearly using vs 2.7? and can you just `import keras` without error?

Comment: when i did `pip install keras` it did not appear to install with that module, but when i downloaded the zip and did `python setup.py install` it installed correctly

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I can import `keras` other modules like what I have edited in the question.

Comment: if you installed it with pip it would have pulled the code from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Keras/0.1.3) which says it was uploaded at 2015-08-27 but if you look at the [github history](https://github.com/fluency03/keras/commits/master/keras/utils/data_utils.py) it was only adapted 3 days ago.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen can I update it to the latest version without reinstalling it using ./setup.py?

Comment: nope. thats what updating means.

Comment: oh! the one in pypi has it in datasets so you would do `import keras.datasets.data_utils`, although expect that to change considering the github

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen it is working when I just use `python`, but it is not working in my eclipse. Do you know how to update my eclipse? I have tried to restart the application and create a new project. Both of them are not working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35905570/4802797) answer is correct but is not complete. Thanks to [Ben J.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6005227/ben-j)'s answer but [Tadhg McDonald-Jensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5827215/tadhg-mcdonald-jensen) is the first one offering me the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905264/keras-importerror-no-module-named-data-utils?noredirect=1#comment59471285_35905264).

**Summarize it**

I was using `pip install keras` to install `keras`, but it did not install the latest version of `keras` according to [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Keras/0.1.3). That is why I could do things like `from keras.models import Sequential`, `from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout`, and `from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM` but not `from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file`. Because it is not in the previous versions.

SO, just `clone` the `keras` from their [github](https://github.com/fchollet/keras), `cd` into it, and run `sudo python setup.py install` will solve this problem.

REMEMBER, if you already did this `pip install keras`, you have to make sure clear all `keras` versions you have installed by doing this `pip uninstall keras` many time until no `keras` existing, then do this `sudo python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 4):

I looked at the tar.gz from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Keras/0.1.3 and there is no file named data_utils.py in the utils folder. However the github does include this file: https://github.com/fchollet/keras.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your issue is resolved by now, if not:

```
sudo pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git --upgrade
```

should do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

this might solve your problem.

```
sudo -H  pip3 install git+https://github.com/fchollet/keras.git --upgrade
```

Comment: Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement upgrade

Comment: yeah, no space after --