# ImportError: No module named data_utils

Tags: python, import, machine-learning, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm extremely new to python and I'm recently trying to understand more about Machine Learning and Neural Nets

I know this is a trivial question but I seem to be having problem importing data_utils on jupyter notebook. Can anyone please help

[image]

Note: I am not using Keras, and I am following the tutorial in [this video](https://youtu.be/SJDEOWLHYVo?list=PL2-dafEMk2A7EEME489DsI468AB0wQsMV&t=213).

Comment: Please don't use links, copy and paste your code and the error into your question.  Does the module load using a command-line program?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the program? it could tell us which packages you'd need to install (e.g. is your program using `keras` or `tflearn`?)

Comment: This question seems to be already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905264/keras-importerror-no-module-named-data-utils

Comment: I'm not using Keras, I'm not sure about tflearn. I'm just using powershell to open tensorflow in jupyter notebook with docker. I'm just attempting to follow a tutorial on youtube. Haven't got as far yet

Answer (score 2):

I was also following the video and went through the same issue, after searching for a while; Here is the link from **Github** [tensorflow_chatbot_required_files](https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_chatbot). You can download from here and copy it to your working directory (python file directory).

Now you will be able to import both.

Comment: Nice! Would be nicer to show how to add this to Python or Anaconda install to setup in an environment, this is only good for this single project.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link that you provided for the video you are using, go to
[this link](https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_chatbot) and download both files into your working directory.

The files you need to download are [data_utils](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_chatbot/master/data_utils.py) and [seq2seq_model](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_chatbot/master/seq2seq_model.py).

But before doing this tutorial try the [tensorflow tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/) found on the tensorflow website, to get you started with this library.

Also, if you are very new to python, I recommend [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/) first.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned about Machine Learning and Neural Nets, I'll assume you're referring to [Keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras).

I'll also assume that you installed it via

```
pip install keras
```

In that case, you need to uninstall it first by running

```
pip uninstall keras
```

Then, clone it from [Github](https://github.com/fchollet/keras), cd into its directory and run

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

[More information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905264/keras-importerror-no-module-named-data-utils/35911254#35911254)

Comment: I'm not using Keras, or rather I'm not exactly sure if I should use Keras. What I'm doing right now is run docker, then run tensorflow in jupyter notebook

Comment: Then you're probably missing data_utils because you haven't installed a package containing data_utils. Do you have a link to the tutorial you're referring to?

Comment: Do I use pip to install the package then? Yes, here it is. https://youtu.be/SJDEOWLHYVo?list=PL2-dafEMk2A7EEME489DsI468AB0wQsMV&t=213 .

Comment: Yes, run the following: pip install numpy scipy six tensorflow

Comment: Thank you! Pardon my ignorance, but I'm really new to this. What do you mean by cloning, cd and run?

Comment: I'm referring to terminal commands. [Cloning](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) is when you duplicate a git repository. [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) means change directory. Run as in run the command in your terminal. If you're new to python, learning how to use the command line, the programming language, git, neural nets and machine learning modules at the same time can be overwhelming. Perhaps start with python basics first?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer @Lee, FeebleOldMan did a good job explaining things here!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using code from tensorflow's github, in that case you need to download https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/translate/data_utils.py into your folder also.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is importing a self-defined module, in order to do that do as follow:

in your case the module is called 'data_util' which contains functions that will be called later as data_util.'function name'.

let say that the data_util which is a python file (.py) is in this directory (C:/Users/xxx/modules), so all what you have to do is to run this line of code in order for python to find your modul when you call import data_util:

```
import sys  
sys.path.append('C:/Users/xxx/modules')  
import data_util
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was using same files.
Just open `seq2seq_model.py` and in line 35 remove from TensorFlow and keep it just `import dat_`