# I cannot import data_utils

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing a chatbot code but after having the latest version , i am getting an error------

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import time
import sys   
import data_utils


ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6d94ab985d76> in <module>()
      4 import time
      5 import sys
----> 6 import data_utils
      7 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_utils'
```

---

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.

Comment: What package is `data_utils`?  Did you install that package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named data\_utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609678/importerror-no-module-named-data-utils)