# Module not found rnn_utils in RNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I need to use this library for building my model but when i had this error.

```
from rnn_utils import *
```

No module named 'rnn_utils'

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609678/importerror-no-module-named-data-utils ?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on you are working on Andrew's coursera class.
You can find a file named 'rnn_utils.py' by click on the 'Coursera' logo. If you are going to implement the course code on another compiler, you should copy the 'rnn_utils.py' file into your current folder

Answer (score 0):

`rnn_utils` is part of the class `nnabla.utils.rnn.PackedSequence`,
so you need to import `nnable`. Try `pip install nnable`,
then in place of `from rnn_utils import *`, try: `import nnabla.utils.rnn as rnn_utils`.

For more info read the nnable [documentation](https://nnabla.readthedocs.io/en/v1.14.0/python/api/utils/rnn.html#rnn-utils):