# ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core (during keras installation)

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, keras, keras-layer

I want to install keras module ([github-link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Keras)). I tried `pip install keras`.It installed 1.2.1. It does not have Graph module as per [this](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4661). Sadly the documentation is also is not updated. So I tried a previous version 1.1.2.and as per the answer by [Chang Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4802797/chang-liu) given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35911254/7103753) ran `sudo python setup.py install` but now I am getting following error

```
 ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core'
```

I have already installed anaconda and during its installation it correctly installed numpy as well.Another thing that I tried was `import keras.layer.container` as according to [documentation](https://keras.io/)  there is class Graph() present in container.Please let me know what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

As the author from the Issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4661)

Graph has been removed. Use the [functional API (see docs).](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/):

> The Keras functional API is the way to go for defining complex models, such as multi-output models, directed acyclic graphs, or models with shared layers.

more clarification:

1. This error could be due to the dependency installations, make sure `numpy` and `scikit-learn` are not having issues during the process.
2. Perhaps due a fresh install of the conda if this is still an issue.

and for the Graph, the first answer still stands, it has been removed.